# Why does the app freeze on a "for" loop?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Why does this loop freeze the GUI? How can I solve this?

```
 -(void)freeze {

      for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {

          NSLog(@"write!");
      }
 }
```

If I call this loop with IBAction (button), button and all app freeze on pressing it. After the loop is done, everything works fine again. What should I do?

Comment: Because you do it on the GUI thread

Comment: Don't call it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: probably because the function is called freeze

Comment: Just kidding. Please provide more information, like debugger information or crash information or stuff like that.

Comment: As @Hyperion points out I think you should read about [concurrency](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change method to

```
-(void)freeze:(id)sender {
    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) { 
        NSLog(@"write!");
    }
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(freeze:) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: wow it's working! Thank You very much!! How can I make in function to perform in background, in example awakeFromNib? I mean without calling?? for example just for loop in background?

Comment: You can wrap any function into your custom method and call it background. But avoid executing UI rendering/drawing in separate thread. It may be a cause of lot of exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a queue to avoid blocking the GUI, example:

```
queue=dispatch_queue_create("my.queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //do blocking stuff here
});
```